# What does the phrase "mercy me" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am reading a story. and there is a sentence in it as follows:

> "Oh, mercy me!" she exclaims,"I can hardly stand it!"

What does the phrase "mercy me" mean in that context? What can I use instead of "mercy me"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Mercy me!" is an old-fashioned expression meaning "God have mercy on me!" and would be used in a situation where the speaker feels alarmed or afraid, or even mildly agitated. You could use "God help me!" or, if you dislike religious oaths, some other exclamation such as "Oh my!".

Comment: Thanks Harvey. In that story she says that when she is surprised with a great offer. So, can the phrase "mercy me" mean "thanks God"?

Comment: It can mean anything which could also be expressed by "Oh!". A great offer. Your dog is killed by a truck. You find a spider in your lunch. Your mother tells you she has won a big prize. Your sister cuts her hair off. A house collapses. Anything surprising or alarming.

Comment: Given that it is, as stated above, just an expression of surprise; other - less obvious - alternatives might include: "Oh no!",  "What the f---!" or even simply "Arrrgh!".

Comment: There are a very large number of exclamations of this type.

Comment: @ARAM I associate "Mercy me!" with "Heaven help me!" more than "Thank God." They often have *opposite* meanings, but sometimes overlap. **The first is an expression of lack** --- of patience, or of providence ("Mercy me! I don't have time for this.") --- or of getting a surprise, often unpleasant ("Mercy me! My neighbor got sick, and I met with him yesterday."), or extremely pleasant and unexpected. ("Mercy me! I've won the lottery! I didn't even dream of winning.")

Comment: **The second is an expression of satisfaction**, especially of getting a result that was desired/expected but uncertain. ("Thank God! The car loan came through."; "Thank God! My daughter did the dishes without being told to.") There are probably other cases I'm missing, of course.

Comment: A girlfriend once told me that her widowed mother used to have a boyfriend who stayed over some nights; the walls were thin in her house; not only could she hear the bed springs creaking, but also (she dissolved into laughter at this point) her mother crying out, very loudly, "Mercy Jesus!" at the climactic moment.

Comment: Many - though certainly not all - Christians would typically avoid using phrases like *God have mercy on me!* and *God help me!*, as these would often be understood to violate the Second Commandment: "Thou shalt not take the name of the Lord thy God in vain."  *God* is typically thought of as a name for God, and so using phrases like *Oh my!*, instead of the other two, can be a very religious practice.

Comment: My girlfriend's mother was an extremely religious woman.

Comment: I know a priest who says "Jesus, Mary and Joseph!" if his car won't start. He is one of the truest Christians I have ever met.

Answer (score 6):

It's an interjection or exclamation that expresses surprise or fear.
It can appear as "mercy", "mercy me", or in other forms.

Here is a dictionary definition:
[Lexico  "mercy" exclamation](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/mercy)
archaic
    Used in expressions of surprise or fear.
    *‘“Mercy me!” uttered Mrs. Garfield’*

An etymological note about the word "mercy" and some derived phrases:
[Etymonline "mercy"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/mercy#etymonline_v_14664)
As an interjection, attested from mid-13c. (short for *may God have mercy*, *have mercy on me*, etc.).

If this exclamation is used these days, it will be taken as humorous because it is so archaic.

Comment: I've heard people use it in all seriousness. I never knew it was archaic. That's interesting.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old-sounding slang used to express shock. It can also be used for emphasis.

An equivalent phrase would be 
"Oh, lord have mercy (on me)".

Two additional notes:

1. "Mercy me" does not follow standard English grammar rules because it is slang.
2. Most people don't actually say "mercy me" anymore, so I would recommend against using it in day-to-day conversation.

Comment: #2 depends on who you hang out with. Certain church ladies say it frequently.